# Find and Replace python script to replaces values in attribute table?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, cursor, find

I am working on a stand alone script in python that will allow to me to specify a shapefile and being able to find a value and replace it with a new value. Does anyone know what code will allow me to do this?

Comment: Yes - the link provided by @Andy contains code that will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this problem, then you'd have to take a look into [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000) (there you will find some examples on how to apply it).

> that will allow to me to specify a shapefile

What do you mean by this? You want your function (presumably you're making one inside your script) that takes in a shapefile?